# Why does ngModel have previous value when registerOnChange fires ngModelChange in Angular

Tags: angular, angular8

My Angular 8 component implements the ControlValueAccessor interface and I have implemented
the registerOnChange method, which I call when an item is selected, passing an array of updated item ids to my callback.

My component selector looks like below where I'm setting a list of items, the model, which is a string array, and the model change event.

```
<app-auto-complete [items]="labels" (ngModelChange)="refresh()"
                                       [(ngModel)]="filter.labels">
</app-auto-complete>
```

Component code shortened for brevity ...

```
registerOnChange(fn: any) {
    this.onChangeCallback = fn;
}

onSelectItem(selectedItem: Lookup) {
    const idx = this.selectedItems.findIndex(i => i.id === selectedItem.id);
    this.selectedItems.push(selectedItem);
    this.onChangeCallback(this.selectedItems.map(i => i.id));
}
```

Refresh method in my parent component

```
refresh() {
 console.log(this.filter.labels); <--- has wrong model value
}
```

When I select and item, I call onChangeCallback passing in the new list of items, which in turn fires the ngModelChange and calls  the refresh method. The problem is that ngModel (filter.labels) always has the previous value, whereas I would have expected it to have the current value.

Does anyone know why ngModel has the previous model value?

BTW - if I pass $event to the refresh method i.e. refresh($event), it does contain the latest value. However, I then need to re-assign this to my model. I would rather have the model automatically updated.

Comment: Probably because your explicit ngModelChange() is called before the implicit ngModelChange() added by [(ngModel)]. If you pass `$event`, it should have the new value.

Comment: You are correct passing $event does have the new value, but then I need to re-assign it. I would like the update to be reflected in the model. I've updated my question with this feedback.

Comment: I don't get it. [(ngModel]] automatically assigns the new value to the model. What do you mean by "I need to re-assign it"? What is this refresh() method actually used for?

Comment: If I change the method signature of refresh to refresh($event), then the value of $event is the correct, up-to-date value. But the value of my model, filters.label is still the previous value. By reassignment I mean that I would need to do something like filter.labels = $event, where I thought filter.labels should be updated automatically since it's the ngmodel.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer. The order of the properties in the selector is important.
Once I changed this, the ngModel contains the correct updated value.

This works, with ngModel **before** ngModelChange

```
<app-auto-complete [items]="labels" [(ngModel)]="filter.labels"
                                           (ngModelChange)="refresh()"></app-auto-complete>
```

This does not work, with ngModel **after** ngModelChange

```
<app-auto-complete [items]="labels" (ngModelChange)="refresh()"
                                       [(ngModel)]="filter.labels"></app-auto-complete>
```